# Create files dynamically in perl

Tags: perl, directory

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Data::Dumper;

my $parent='/source';
my $destdir='/destination';

#open parent directory
opendir(DIR, $parent) or die "Can't open the current directory: $!\n";

# read directory names in that directory into @names 
my @dirs = grep {-d "$parent/$_" && ! /^\.{1,2}$/} readdir(DIR);

#my $pm=new Parallel::ForkManager();

foreach (@dirs)
{
    #$pm -> start and next;
    #do only if a folder contains .fastq.gz files
    my @txt = <$parent/$_/*.fastq.gz>;
    if(@txt)
    {         
        system("zcat $parent/$_/*R1*.fastq.gz | gzip > $destdir/$_.R1.fastq.gz");
        system("zcat $parent/$_/*R2*.fastq.gz | gzip > $destdir/$_.R2.fastq.gz");
        print "Inside $_ folder \n";
    }
    #$pm -> finish;
}
```

Hi everyone,
So I have a source "$parent/" directory. There are 32 sub-directories in it. Each directory contains some *R1*.fastq.gz files and *R2*.fastq.gz files. I have to merge the *R1*.fastq.gz files into one R1.fastq.gz file and similarly for *R2*.fastq.gz files. The merged fastq.gz files are stored in destination directory "$destdir/". I also want the name of the merged fastq.gz files to match the name of the sub-directory from which it was merged and created (lines 23 & 24). When I run my code, I get the following errors:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /destination/Fastqc.R1.fastq.gz: Directory nonexistent 
sh: 1: cannot create /destination/Fastqc.R2.fastq.gz: Directory nonexistent
```

For e.g. here Fastqc comes from the name of my directory from which I am creating merged files. 
I have tried but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Can someone help?

When I use

```
system("zcat $parent/$_/*R1*.fastq.gz | gzip > $_.R1.fastq.gz"); instead of 
system("zcat $parent/$_/*R1*.fastq.gz | gzip > $destdir/$_.R1.fastq.gz");
```

it works fine.

Comment: I already have that directory given by $destdir in my system

Comment: @user2703967, Your system disagrees

Comment: The problem could be related to your last of proper construction of shell command. (e.g. Consider what would happen if you included a space in `$destdir`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have tried changing $destdir to other directories and it gives me the same error. When I don't use $destdir/ while creating the file it works fine. So it maybe something related to the syntax of lines 23 & 24.

Comment: I got it. Thanks everyone. It was a silly mistake from my end, I was using /destination instead of /home/destination. So yes, each one of you is correct, I was really referring to a non-existent directory. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works fine. It was a silly mistake from my end, I was referring to '/destination' instead of '/home/destination' in $destdir. In essence, I was really referring to a non-existent directory.